# How can I run Verilog code with data at a specific time in the past?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim, questasim, tcl

My simulation takes hours until it's stopped from my SystemVerilog code using `$stop;`.

When it stops, to have proper information, I need to run a Verilog task/function at a certain time before it stopped. The function reads the memory and prints various information.

Is there a way to do that?

Otherwise, what would be the appropriate alternative?

How do verification engineers debug such a situation?

There is the `call` Tcl command, but it doesn't have the time parameter, and once the error has happened, it's too late. Maybe the `examine` Tcl command can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set up your simulations so that output can be controlled by command line switch and `$value$plusargs` then there is no need to recompile your design if you want to change what gets printed. The UVM has greater print control than this.

For example (leaving it to you to add better error checking)

```
realtime starttime, stoptime;
bit printed;
initial fork
    if ($value$plusargs("starttime=%g",starttime)
         begin
         $display("print starting at %t", starttime)
         #(starttime) printed = 1;
         end
    if ($value$plusargs("stoptime=%g",stoptime)
         begin
         $display("print stoping at %t", stoptime)
         #(starttime) printed = 0;
         end
    join
```

Then wrap all your printing with

```
if (printed)
   call_my_print_functions;
```

There are a few approaches people take to this verification problem

1. Set up your simulation to run as fast as possible. Maximize optimization by turning off all access and dumping. Print out as little information as possible just enough to know that your test has passed or failed and what time in the simulation things started going wrong. Then go back and restart your simulation with the `printed` flag that turns the printing on at the needed time (use a command line $value$plusargs).
2. A variation of 1. is using checkpoint to save the entire state of the simulation at regular intervals. Then go back to the last checkpoint before you want to start printing data. Turn the flag on at the appropriate time when restoring the checkpoint. Since the $value$plusargs function got called at time 0, you'll have use a simulator command line option to set the `printed` flag.
3. Save the data you want printed to Questa's waveform database and use the Tcl `searchlog` command to print the data you want. You would have to write a Tcl script to format the data the way you want it.
4. Output the data you want printed in a compact binary form using whatever language you want (SystemVerilog/C/Python) to read the data back in and then print it the way you want.

Comment: (2.) would be perfect for me. I'm unfortunately using free version of Modelsim SE that doesn't support `checkpoint/restore` command. But I believe adding a `$display` would force the recompilation and then the data wouldn't be aligned with the existing checkpoint I restore.

Comment: 3 and 4: I hoped avoiding different tools but it seems to be my only option. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually I misread (1), it seems interesting. Could you elaborate a bit more on it? I couldn't find how to reset the simulation back at a specific time (`restart` goes back to time 0). Having a print-enable-flag at 0 then force it to 1 when necessary, then continue the simulation would be an excellent alternative!

Comment: I updated my answer with example code. You can only restart the simulation back to time 0 unless you use checkpoint. There is no need to recompile the design.

Comment: 3. and 4. can be done with the same tool.

Answer (score 2):

> Otherwise, what would be the appropriate alternative?
>
> How do verification engineers debug such a situation?

The standard way to debug Verilog simulations is to dump a waveform database.  The generic format supported by all simulators is VCD.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 21.7 *Value change dump (VCD) files*.

```
initial begin
    $dumpfile("waves.vcd");
    $dumpvars;
end
```

Then you can view the waveforms in your simulator's waveform viewer.  This stores the values of all signals at all times during the simulation.

Also refer to the documentation for your simulator for other methods of waveform dumping.

Comment: That's the basic way of debugging, my design is much more complicated and data must be processed for being useful. I already have all the systemverilog functions to analyze and display what's going on. But printing it would make my transcript being 100sGB...

Comment: Yes and I know any non-junior verif. eng. don't only do that since it's very limited. What if you have a 1MB memory or combinatory logic... Waveforms are good for easy and straightforward signals, not to show advanced cases.

Comment: @Alexis what exactly is the problem with 100 GBs of trace? If you need the data, you need the data, and since you can't know at the time of simulation whether you'll need it later on, you **have** to log it. Of course, you'd then postprocess the VCD to only extract the part of the data that's relevant to you .

Comment: It seems you all ignore my question and my need. Having data is a thing, I don't care to have the waveforms, they don't tell me anything. I need to take past data and call a systemverilog function to it that will display me what I need. If now, you tell me I have to dev the same function in a different language and extract data from the VCD file, I'd tell you there is a serious problem in the HW world.

Comment: 100s GBs isn't an issue per-se, but having to run the function at each event would slow down the simulation by 10x, makes no sense since all the data the function calls is already stored by modelsim (I can see the memories).